# How can I create a nebula in Blender using Blender Render instead of Cycles?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I've looked over the internet for an hour or so, trying to find a tutorial for creating a nebula without Cycles in Blender Render, but I found nothing? Is it really not possible or am I just a bad googler?

Comment: Everything is possible, most people just choose the tool which is easiest/fastest to use for each specific case. Is there a reason why you don't want to use Cycles?

Comment: I have a complex starship model designed for blender internal that I would like to avoid re-doing since it would take me forever.

Comment: You would only need to convert your materials. You could give [this script](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/365/30849) a try.

Comment: You can also combine scenes with cycles and internal [in the compositor](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/5522/30849).

Comment: The script sounds great! I installed the addon. Sadly, the script you linked points to a dead page linking to an archived article. Sadly, I'm not sure how I should proceed / run the script.

Comment: If you're only using image texture and all your object are unwrapped, try [this one](https://github.com/scorpion81/blender-addons-contrib/blob/master/materials_cycles_converter.py). A quick google search turned up a lot of people writing their own script. Maybe you could pick one, link it in the question, and then explain what it's missing.

Comment: Objects in space are all very distant. So the nebula and the ship will not affect each other's look. So, the easiest way is to render another scene in cycles, as Leander said, and then composite both in compositor. Of course, the camera must be the same (Ctrl+L) - link the camera to the second scene.

Comment: Linking the objects is the way I am going to proceed, many thanks for the advice to both of you :)